# How do different sizes of Hnefatafl play?

Tags: hnefatafl

There are some [variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafl_games#Tafl_variants) of Tafl games that involve differently sized boards. Obviously there is more to a game than its size, but how do the different variations of the board size affect play?

Comment: Don't know that anything beyond the obvious can be said. Smaller boards with small numbers of men will result in play having familiar patterns. Large numbers of men and larger boards have more strategy, but the game can get tedious since it takes a long time to play.

Comment: Since the rules of the game seem to have been partially lost in time, which specific rules did you have in mind?